# Triple integrals using spherical coordinates with a sphere not centered at the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F(x,y,z)=(6x,-2y,5z)$ a vector field and $S$ the surface of the sphere centered at $(1,0,1)$ e radius $5$. Find the flux of $F$ across the surface $S$.

I want to use the Gauss theorem, and my problem is when i use spherical coordinates how can i found the bounds for $\rho$, $\psi$ if the sphere is not centered at the origin.

Thank you

Comment: the integral of a "constant" over a ball is equal to the product of that constant and the volume of ball.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

Why don't you use integration by substitution using a translation in order to reduce the problem to one where the sphere is centered at the origin?